# Nexus 7 - Stuck in recovery mode

Tags: cyanogenmod, recovery-mode, nexus-7, clockworkmod-recovery

So I bought a nexus 7 a while ago and after a while I jailbroke the nexus 7 and installed cyanogenMod. I'll be very honest I followed a tutorial online and it worked. After a while I was stupid enough to install an unstable version. Which caused my nexus to basically break ( when I say break I mean I couldnt get past the recovery mode screen).

Currently I am stuck in recovery mode. I turned my nexus on today after years.
And I see this ( I apologise for the bad quality of the image )[image]

I have no idea where to go from here. How Do I fix this? Whats the next step.
I honestly have no clue at all.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My advice would be use a Nexus toolkit to restore your device back to stock. It's often the easiest way. And in future make sure you make a backup in recovery before installing experimental builds

Comment: @1990clb Thank you. Would you happen to have any tutorials that I can follow to get it back to stock? Also I have a macbook air, any idea where I'll still be able to download and work with nexus toolkit?